# Problema en graficar histograma en Distribución de Frecuencias Cuantitativa

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

Tengo la siguiente distribución de frecuencia:

[image: Distribución de Frecuencias]

El código que elaboré para elaborar el histograma es:

```
library(dplyr)

library(ggplot2)

midf <- data.frame("x" = c(rep(1975,1), rep(1985,6), rep(1995,17), rep(2005,24), rep(2015,1)))

g1 <- ggplot(midf)

g1 <- g1 + aes ( x = x)

g1 <- g1 + geom_histogram () + geom_histogram(bins=5, position = 'identity', alpha = 0.8)

g1 <- g1 + xlab ("Años de Antiguedad")

g1 <- g1 + ylab ("Cantidad de Objetos")

g1 <- g1 + ggtitle ("Trabajo de Aplicación", subtitle = "Antiguedad de Objetos Encontrados en Océano")

g1 <- g1 + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(-2,26), xlim=c(1970,2020))

g1
```

Sin embargo no me logra quedar un histograma (las columnas juntas y centradas en la marca de clase), mas bien es un gráfico de barras y se trata de una distribución cuantitativa. Alguien sabe como puedo construir adecuadamente el histograma?

Este es el gráfico que me queda:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

La solución es usar breaks en el histograma y en el eje x
Los pasos a seguir serían:

1. En `geom_histogram()` definir `breaks` para crear los grupos de manera adequada. En tu caso, `seq(1970,2020,by=10)` crearía el año de inicio de cada década.
2. Para las etiquetas en los ejes, con `scale_x_continuous(breaks=)` controlamos la posición de las etiquetas. Aqui podríamos usar directamente `unique(sort(midf$x))`.

```r
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)

midf <- data.frame("x" = c(
  rep(1975, 1), rep(1985, 6), rep(1995, 17), rep(2005, 24), rep(2015, 1)
))

ggplot(midf, aes(x)) +
  # Histograma
  geom_histogram(
    # Para crear las categorías (bins) en ggplot2
    breaks = seq(1970, 2020, by = 10),
    alpha = 0.8
  ) +
  # Para centrar las etiquetas
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(sort(midf$x))) +
  xlab("Años de Antiguedad") +
  ylab("Cantidad de Objetos") +
  ggtitle("Trabajo de Aplicación",
    subtitle = "Antiguedad de Objetos Encontrados en Océano"
  ) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-2, 26), xlim = c(1970, 2020))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>